# Changing just the text in a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like so:

```
<div class="comment">
    Some text goes here.
    <div class="controls">
      Controls go here.
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I replace just "Some text goes here" without affecting the `controls` div?

Clearly another div can be added around "Some text goes here", and then its contents replaced, but for the sake of this question assume that I cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible without modifying the existing HTML. Just use jQuery to find the text node and then change its value by directly accessing the DOM.

```
$('.comment').contents()[0].nodeValue = 'Some other text goes here.';
```

See the jQuery documentation for [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and the MDN documentation for [.nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "div" around the text, maybe an span so it is inline. Or use:

```
<div class="comment">
    Some text goes here.
    <div class="controls">
      Controls go here.
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var c = $('.comment').eq(0);
    c.html(c.html().replace('Some text goes here', 'Blah blah blah'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like this:

```
$(function() {
    var children = $('.comment').children();
    $('.comment').text('har').append(children);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to locate `controls` div, then convert it to DOM node and use native JS to change text

```
var textNode=$('.comment').find('.controls')[0].previousSibling
    textNode.nodeValue='New Text From Script'
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tmGDW/